# Run testng.xml on Linux Machine

Tags: java, linux, selenium, testng

I Want to run `testng.xml` on **Linux** system. The following command works well in **Windows**:

```
java -cp 
"%ProjectPath%\jars\*;%ProjectPath%\bin\*;%ProjectPath%\external\tools\*" 
org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
```

But the same command produces following error on **Linux**:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Comment: is your class being compiled?

Comment: normally path names have a slight difference in Linux systems. you need to use slash `/` instead of a backslash.

Comment: You might want to make 3 changes : (1) Change `%ProjectPath%` to `$ProjectPath` (2) Replace `\` with `/` (3). Replace `;` with `:` and then try running your tests. That should fix.

Comment: @SarahAziziyan Thanku , it worked with "/".

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanx, It worked with :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to make 3 changes :

1. Change `%ProjectPath%` to `$ProjectPath`
2. Replace `\` with `/`
3. Replace `;` with `:` and then try running your tests. That should fix.